# Calculating Grade Averages, program continually errors out

Tags: java, arrays

My job for this code is to calculate the grades and final weighted average grade and the output them in a table. I'm having trouble doing this because I continually get an array out of bounds where it says:

```
examAverage[index] = ...etc
```

My MAX_STUDENTS is 200 because that is the highest amount of students that can have their grades stored in my program. Please help me figure out what variables I need to change to make this program work well. If there is anymore information I need to provide just let me know. Here is the rest of my code:

```
if (choice == 2) {

            //Index counters for averages
            int examIndex = 0;
            int quizIndex = 0;
            int hwIndex = 0;
            int gradeAveragingIndex = 0;

            //loop finding the gradeAverage
            for(int index = 0; index<=MAX_STUDENTS; index++){
                examAverage[index] = (exams[examIndex] + exams[examIndex+1] + exams[examIndex+2]) / numExams;
                quizAverage[index] = (quizzes[quizIndex] + quizzes[quizIndex+1] + quizzes[quizIndex+2]) / numQuizzes;
                hwAverage[index] = (hw[hwIndex] + hw[hwIndex+1] + hw[hwIndex+2]) / numHW;
                gradeAverage[index] = ((examAverage[gradeAveragingIndex] * examWeight) + (quizAverage[gradeAveragingIndex] * quizWeight) + (hwAverage[gradeAveragingIndex] * hwWeight) / numExams);

                examIndex+=3;
                quizIndex+=3;
                hwIndex+=3;
                gradeAveragingIndex++;

            }

            System.out.println("Display student grades & statistics");

            //Formatting for the heading of my grade table
            System.out.printf("%-10s","Name");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
            System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
            System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
            System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Grade\n");

            //declaring index counters
            int studentNameIndex = 0;
            int examGradeIndex = 0;
            int quizGradeIndex = 0;
            int homeworkGradeIndex = 0;
            int gradeAverageIndex = 0;

            //for loop for the output of exams, quizzes, homework, and grade average
            for(int index = 0; index < studentNames.length; index++) {
                System.out.printf("%-10s",studentNames[studentNameIndex]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex+1]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex+2]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[quizGradeIndex]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[quizGradeIndex+1]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[quizGradeIndex+2]);
                System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[homeworkGradeIndex]);
                System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[homeworkGradeIndex+1]);
                System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[homeworkGradeIndex+2]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",gradeAverage[gradeAverageIndex] + "\n");

                studentNameIndex++;
                examGradeIndex+=3;
                quizGradeIndex+=3;
                homeworkGradeIndex+=3;
                gradeAverageIndex++;
            }

                }
```

Comment: How large is the `examAverage` array?

Comment: Post your stacktrace and tell what you searched about that error and learned from it

Comment: @Reddy, you and I both know the stack trace isn't going to say anything useful other than ArrayOutOfBoundsException on the first line, every other line will be useless to this program. It'll just point him to the line where theerror happened. Which I am sure he knows what line that is.

Comment: @Daniel, you may have found this error quicker with a google search of "What usually causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions".

Comment: @August, my exam average array is 200.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
for(int index = 0; index<=MAX_STUDENTS; index++){
```

should be:

```
for(int index = 0; index<MAX_STUDENTS; index++){
```

Just change `<=` to `<`.

Now your program is trying to access the 200th element of a 200 element array. The 200 element array is indexed from 0 to 199, which means that 200 is out of bounds. You need to go from 0 to 199, and that change will do just that.

Comment: Hey Matthew, thanks for the help. I changed that, but now I get an index out of bounds at my next line of code `examAverage[index] = (exams[examIndex] + exams[examIndex+1] + exams[examIndex+2]) / numExams;`

Comment: That's because your in your loop, you go until you are at the last index, then try to access the two after it. Your condition in your for loop should be changed like this: "for(int index = 0; index + 2 < studentNames.length; index++)"

Comment: I changed it to that, but it still does not work. I may have figured out what my problem is. My exams array is only equal numExams, or however many exams the user inputs. Usually this is only 3. Could that be the problem? Also how would I fix that problem then.

Comment: Yes that's your problem, you'll want to make your condition for the for loop, go until the number of exams they entered.

Comment: that still didn't fix it, there's still a problem with this line of code `examAverage[index] = (exams[examIndex] + exams[examIndex+1] + exams[examIndex+2]) / numExams;` it says the array is out of bounds.Specifically "ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: 0

Comment: That means it's happening when the index is 0, which means the array was never made properly. Can you post the code where you initialize this array?

Comment: Here's where I declared gradeAverage: `double[] gradeAverage = new double[MAX_STUDENTS];` and here's where I declared exams: `double[] exams = new double[numExams];`

Comment: Can you copy all of your code and paste it at pastebin, then send me the link. I'll look through all of it and see if I can find the problem.

Comment: Here's the link: http://pastebin.com/mBUgQTzL   There's a large amount of commented out code that you can just ignore, it was my first go at choice #1. I got some help and made it better and haven't gotten around to deleting the old commented code.

Comment: The problem is numExams is set to 0 right before you make an array of numExams size. You'll need to get the number of exams and then make your array that size. (Referring to lines 68 & 73)

Comment: Where can I put it in my code that I'll be able to use it everywhere, but the numExams will still increment with my 1st choice? The 1st choice is where numExams get's its value.

Comment: It looks like after 154 and before 157, you know how many exams you'll have, and don't need the array before that. So declare the arrays there.

Comment: That makes the exam arrays in my if ==choice2 loop error out because the double exams is created in if ==choice1 then.

Comment: does that make sense what I said? Basically I put that double exams array into a loop and the loop ends. This isn't good because I need to use the exams array in other loops as well.

Comment: Right, can you declare it outside of the loop, like you have now. Then, when someone chooses to enter data, you can initialize it to the size you based on what size they need.